# Make a QR quine

Tags: code-challenge, graphical-output

A "qruine" if you will :)

Design a QR code that legibly spells with its pixels (or the space between them) the text that it scans to.

For example, this QR code scans to the letter A, and also spells out A in white:

[image]

There are 4 categories, one for each mode of QR code: numeric, alphanumeric, byte, and kanji. Please state which category your submission is for.

In order to prevent trivial solutions like "------------", in all categories except numeric mode the text must be coherent in a natural language. (In numeric mode the winner will be a large number of 1s, obviously.)

Your score is 2*l* ÷ *h*, where *l* is the length of the text and *h* is the width of the QR code in QR dots (not necessarily the same as screen pixels). Highest score in each category wins. The score of the sample QR code is (2*1 character / 97 dots wide) = 0.02.

Comment: The idea is nice, but the problem is the word "_legibly_": it should be possible to _objectively_ decide if the text is legible or not, so that everyone agrees if an answer is valid or not. Unless you find a way to make that objective, I think the challenge should be closed, unfortunately

Comment: A popularity challenge may be better as the scoring criterion, but it's still hard to judge if a QR code spells a letter

Comment: I think this challenge would be better if, instead of spelling the source code with the pixels of the QR code, you just print a QR code that encodes the program itself.