# Build a program that outputs itself encoded as a QR

Tags: code-golf, quine, encoding

The goal is simple. Write a program that outputs itself encoded as a QR code.

A QR code is a way to encode data in a black and white image, similar to a 2D image.

An example implementation can be found [here.](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder)

The QR code is displayed as text, where each pixel is either a "#" for a  black pixel, or a space for a white pixel, and pixels are separated by spaces, like so:

```
# # # # # # #   # # # #     # # # # # # #
#           #           #   #           #
#   # # #   #   # #     #   #   # # #   #
#   # # #   #       #   #   #   # # #   #
#   # # #   #       #   #   #   # # #   #
#           #               #           #
# # # # # # #   #   #   #   # # # # # # #
                #   # #
#   #     # #     # #     # #       #   #
  # # #   #   #   #   # #   #     #   # #
#   # #   # # #   # # # # # #   #       #
# # #         # #         # # # #
# # # # #   #   #     #     #   #     #
                      # # # #
# # # # # # #       #   # #   # #   #   #
#           #   #         # # # #
#   # # #   #         #     #   #     #
#   # # #   #     #     # # # # #
#   # # #   #   #   #   # #   # #   #   #
#           #     # #       # # #   # # #
# # # # # # #   #           #   #   #   #
```

Quine rules (no reading source code) apply.

This is code golf, so shortest program wins!

Comment: Can you clarify if we can use characters other than `#`, or omit the spaces between them?

Comment: It's suggested to explain important parts of the challenge, like what a QR code is. If that is too complicated, you can at least link to relevant information.

Comment: You should also explain how to output a QR code as text.  An example alone is not sufficient as Redwolf's question indicates.

Comment: [similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219787/make-a-qr-quine)

Comment: IMHO the ASCII-art QR code is a bit awkward, and I think that you should also be allowed to output as an image ([tag:graphical-output]).

Comment: Does it have to be a proper quine (not allowed to read its source code)?

Comment: @xigoi yes, it isn't allowed to read source code, although empty code is allowed bc it  doesn't work anyways

Comment: `qrencode -t ASCII` outputs QR codes with `##` for each pixel instead of `# `. I'd recommend using `##` as it's much easier to scan.